# What's the waiting time for the residence card?

Tags: united-kingdom, immigration

I recently received my certificate of application for a EU citizen family member residence card. Although the certificate states I am allowed to work, I have had many difficulties to be hired due to the fact that my passport is still with the Home Office. Even if I am allowed to work, the fact of not having my passport with me makes it very difficult as there is no other official way for me to prove my identity.

This certificate states that my residence card will be decided within six months of the application date. I applied the second week of February and I sent my Biometric information on April 1st. Taking this information into account, does anyone have any idea how long more I have to wait for the residence card?

Thank you

Comment: How long did you end up waiting?